# Robot Framework MAC Address test and validation

Tags: linux, robotframework

I run Robot Framework test and it fails me everytime, even I get 1 line or so.

Here is the terminal output for cat command:

```
RobotFramework:~$ cat macaddresses.txt | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | head -n 1
00:01:c0:24:a3:3b
```

Here is latest Example:

```
Check MAC Addresses
    ${macaddress}=    Execute Command    ifconfig | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' >> macaddresses.txt
    ${checkmac}=    Execute Command    cat macaddresses.txt | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | head -n 1
    Should Contain    ${checkmac}    ([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}
    Set Test Message    ${checkmac}
```

If I run it straight from cmd when connected with SSH it works fine and it prints one line of MAC Addressess and that should be fine?

But still I get fail everytime

And here is fail results:

```
Test MAC Addresses | FAIL |
'00:01:c0:24:a3:3b' does not contain '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Debugging Log:

```
20230124 20:08:16.397 :  INFO : ${checkmac} = 00:01:c0:24:a3:3b
```

```
20230124 20:08:16.398 :  FAIL : '00:01:c0:24:a3:3b' does not contain '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Edit:

Also tried Keyword Should Match Regexp

```
Should Match Regexp    ${checkmac}    ([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}
```

And got error:

```
20230124 20:24:29.521 :  FAIL : '00:01:c0:24:a3:3b' does not match '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `grep` uses a different representation for hex numbers, as you did used `:xdigit:`. I did not researched, but this looks like a non-standard for Regular Expressions (and first time I see it).

However, I experimented in https://regex101.com/ using Python mode, because that is what Robot Framework uses, and got the following result:

```
([\d|[a-f]{1,2}:){5}([\d|[a-f]{1,2})
```

As you can see, each hex pair is constructed with any digit or a-f letters.

This can be validated, with the following Robot Framework test case:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test RegEx
    ${input}=    Set Variable    00:01:c0:24:a3:3b
    ${regex}=    Set Variable    ([\\d|[a-f]{1,2}:){5}([\\d|[a-f]{1,2})
    ${result}=    Should Match Regexp    ${input}    ${regex}
```

Here is the execution log:

```
Starting test: Test Timeouts.Test RegEx
20230124 21:22:23.128 :  INFO : ${input} = 00:01:c0:24:a3:3b
20230124 21:22:23.130 :  INFO : ${regex} = ([\d|[a-f]{1,2}:){5}([\d|[a-f]{1,2})
20230124 21:22:23.132 :  INFO : ${result} = ['00:01:c0:24:a3:3b', 'a3:', '3b']
Ending test: Test Timeouts.Test RegEx
```